# Roots of: $2(x+2)(x-1)^3-3(x-1)^2(x+2)^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is maybe a stupid question, but I want to find the roots of:

> $$2(x+2)(x-1)^3-3(x-1)^2(x+2)^2=0$$

What that I did:

$$\underbrace{2(x+2)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)}_{A}-\underbrace{3(x-1)(x-1)(x+2)(x+2)}_{B}=0$$

So the roots are when $A$ and $B$ are both zeros when $x=1$ and $x=-2$

My questions:

$1)$ Is there an easy way to see that $x=-8$ is a root too?

$2)$ The degree of this polynomial is $4$, so I should have $4$ roots, and here I have only $3$

Comment: When you do a full factorization as the answers show, you'll see $(x-1)^2$. The square makes x=1 a double root. So it counts twice.

Comment: Note that you should have $4$ roots only if you consider complex roots. If you don't know what it is, you should consider the following: $x^{4}+1=0$. This equation admits no REAL solution. So if you are looking for real solutions, a polynomial of degree $2n$ (for some $n\geq 1$) has between $0$ and $2n$ real roots, while a polynomial of degree $2n-1$ (for some $n\geq 1$) has between $1$ and $2n-1$ real roots.
And as Ameet Sharma points it out, you have to mind the so-called multiplicity  of the roots.

Comment: The reason this $4$'th degree polynomial has only $3$ roots is because $1$ is a [multiple root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Distributive Property.

$$2(x+2)(x-1)^3-3(x-1)^2(x+2)^2$$

$$=\underbrace{(x+2)(x-1)^2}_{\text{common factor}}\left(2(x-1)\right)-\underbrace{(x+2)(x-1)^2}_{\text{common factor}}(3(x+2))$$

$$=(x+2)(x-1)^2\left(2(x-1)-3(x+2)\right)$$
$$=(x+2)(x-1)^2(-(x+8))$$

Answer (score 2):

First advice: when you are looking for roots of a polynomial, factorize as much as you can. You have $(x-1)^2$ and $(x-1)^3$, so you  can factorize  $(x-1)^2$.   You have $(x+2)$ and $(x+2)^2$, so you  can factorize  $(x+2)$. Thus you get:
$$(x+2)(x-1)^2 (2(x-1)-3(x+2))\,. $$ So:

1. For question 1,  the  $-8$ root should be evident (develop the  last term)
2. For question 2: look at powers, $(x-1)^2$ means that $1$ is a root, twice. So your roots are $-8$, $-2$ and  $1$ and $1$ again.

Answer (score 1):

**Ніnt:**
$$2(x+2)(x-1)^3-3(x-1)^2(x+2)^2=- \left( x+8 \right)  \left( x+2 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2(x+2)(x-1)^3-3(x-1)^2(x+2)^2=0$$
$$(x-1)^2(x+2)\left[2(x-1)-3(x+2)\right]=0$$
$$(x-1)^2(x+2)(-x-8)=0$$
$$(x-1)^2(x+2)(x+8)=0$$

So this polynomial of degree $4$ has $4$ real roots i.e. $1,1,-2,-8$.

Answer (score 1):

Well

$2(x+2)(x-1)^{3}-3(x-1)^{2}(x+2)^{2}=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)^{2}(x+2)[2(x-1)-3(x+2)]=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)^{2}(x+2)(-x-8)=0 $

From here it should be clear why $x=-8$ is also a root.

This is called [factoring](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/factoring.html).

Comment: Taypo? that should be $x=\color{red}-8$

Comment: $-x-8$  makes it clear that $x=-8$ is also a root. This is called "taking care of signs"

Comment: Haha the irony. I'll fix that.